# D3, good gear, paragon and still weak

Tags: diablo-iii

So I have reached paragon 701 with my Crusader. I have a complete Ancient Roland Legacy set, and I have very good weapon (Fate of the fell, ancient, 4320 DMG, +1400 STR, augmented +315 STR etc. Compass rose and Trav.pledge, DPS 2,6M.

I have followed the build Roland + Sweep, but I am too weak, not even beating G.Rift 50-55.

What is the key? I am killing a skeleton 30 seconds, while a player with way worse gear and paragon comes along and kills it with a single shot..

Comment: It would help if you posted a link to your battle.net account. Also Fate of the Fell is a bad weapon, as Heaven's Fury builds aren't viable.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue is that the Roland set just isn't very good. It is getting a buff in the next patch (2.5), but I don't know if it will be enough to make it a good set or not.

As of this writing (Patch 2.4.3) the top Crusader builds are [Hammerdin](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/crusader-holy-hammerdin-build-with-blessed-hammer-and-seeker-of-the-light-patch-2-4-3-season-9) (using the Seeker of the Light set) and [Legacy of Nightmare Bombardment](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/crusader-endgame-bombardment-build-with-the-legacy-of-nightmares-set-patch-2-4-3-season-9) (using the Legacy of Nightmare set with ancient legendaries). If you want to push higher greater rifts, I'd focus on farming the items needed for those builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a guide for Roland's set [here](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/crusader-sweep-attack-lightning-build-with-the-rolands-set-patch-2-4-3-season-9).  Some of the highlights based on what you said you already have are:

1. Use the Trip Attack rune with Sweep Attack combined with the shield [Denial](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/denial), which increases the damage of your sweep attack based on the number of enemies hit by the previous use.  In addition, get extra lightning damage on your gear to increase Sweep Attack's power.
2. Use [Convention of Elements](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/convention-of-elements) for extra burst while it is empowering the damage type of your sweep attack (the above rune is lightning)
3. Put [Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/obsidian-ring-of-the-zodiac) in your cube and use [Akarat's Champion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/akarats-champion), which will allow you to use it to get extra damage and protection for more difficult engagements like elites